# Can't access web app running locally with CouchDB

Tags: web, couchdb

I have a web app running locally with CouchDB. I'm trying to access the app from my mobile and tablet but I can't access it. I'm puzzled... The app runs on localhost:5984/myDb/_design/myDesign/mypage.html.Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Duh... It's the bind address, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so for any person, like me, who couldn't come up with the reason why... :)

In the default configuration (local.ini) the bind_address option is set to 127.0.0.1. If you change the bind_address option to 0.0.0.0, then you'll be able to access CouchDB remotely. Restart CouchDB after making this change.